# prepend to Swift Array and update UICollectionView - correct reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to create a lazy loading method for a messaging View using "willDisplayCell" - the user should be scrolling upwards, messages get fetched and prepended

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  if messagesCollection.count >= 10 {

    var counter = 1

    if indexPath == NSIndexPath(forItem: counter, inSection: 0) {
      self.appendSpinner()              
      self.messageSkip = self.messageSkip + 10
      self.getMessages(self, skip: self.messageSkip)
    }       
  }   
}
```

this will fire a Socket.IO event to get messages, which will trigger

```
func loadMessages(messages:[Message]) {

  var reverted = messages.reverse() //reverse messages to be most recent on bottom
  self.messagesCollection = self.messagesCollection + messages.reverse()

  //so far its working as intended, all messages line up nicely
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

this will leave me in an infinite loop - because I will always be showing indexPath 1, a second attempt using batch updates yields the same result:

```
func loadMessages(messages:[Message]) {

  var reverted = messages.reverse()          
  self.messagesCollection = reverted+self.messagesCollection
  var reloadCells = [NSIndexPath]()

  for (index,singleMessage) in enumerate(reverted) {              
    var singleReloadCell = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    reloadCells.append(singleReloadCell)            
  }

  println(reloadCells)          
  self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({          
    self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(reloadCells as [AnyObject])}, completion: nil)              
  }
}
```

any hints would be appreciated.